# Storing an image using OutputStream

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an uploaded Image file from browser,which i received using InputStream

Html:

```
<form method="POST" action='Seller_database' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="img_input"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

I am receiving the values through an InputStream in servlet,

```
Part img=request.getPart("img_input");
InputStream fileContent = img.getInputStream();
```

Now i wanted to store the inputed image file into a particular folder.

Please suggest whether to use OutputStream or ImageOutputStream or any other way

Comment: [`Files.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `ImageIO` class.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(fileContent); //fileContent is your InputStream
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("savedFile.jpg");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Comment: But i have the image in InputStream and not in ImageInputStream ,So i am not able to use ImageOutputStream

Comment: `BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(fileContent); //fileContent is your InputStream

ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("savedFile.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be obtained by using the **OutputStream** and using **Files.copy** function

```
  InputStream fileContent = img.getInputStream();
   Path img_destination=Paths.get("H://Products_image//"+fileName);//The Output file path with the file name,as without file name it wont get created.
 Files.copy(fileContent,img_destination);//InputStream to the Path in which file needs to be copied
```